# Which is the event when product is clicked

Tags: magento-1.9, product, event-observer, magento-1

I want to create observer ,when a product is clicked ,can you tell me **which is the event** and how can I see in my observer code **which product was clicked and to get information about it** ?

This is my config.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
        <modules>
        <Solvingmagento_OrderExport>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Solvingmagento_OrderExport>
        </modules>
        <global>
        <events>
            <catalog_controller_product_view>
            <observers>
                <custom_catalog_controller_product_view>
                    <class>solvingmagento_orderexport/observer</class>
                    <method>observerProductClicked</method>
                </custom_catalog_controller_product_view>
            </observers>
        </catalog_controller_product_view>
        </events>

        <helpers>
            <orderexport>
            <class>Solvingmagento_OrderExport_Helper</class>
            </orderexport>
        </helpers>
        </global>
    </config>
```

and my Observer.php :

class SolvingMagento_OrderExport_Model_Observer{

```
public function observerProductClicked(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $product = $observer->getProduct();
    // Do what you want with the product
    echo $product;
    var_dump($_SERVER);
    die('chekc');
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

To observe a product clicked/viewed you need to use the following event: `catalog_controller_product_view`

In your `config.xml` add the following to your `<global>` tag:

```
    <events>
        <catalog_controller_product_view>
            <observers>
                <custom_catalog_controller_product_view>
                    <class>yourmodule/observer</class>
                    <method>observeProduct</method>
                </custom_catalog_controller_product_view>
            </observers>
        </catalog_controller_product_view>
    <events>
```

NB: you will need to replace `module/observer` with your module class name.

Then in your `Observer.php` you can do:

```
<?php

class Vendor_Module_Model_Observer {
    public function observerProductClicked(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getProduct();
        // Do what you want with the product

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you ,but its not working ,my data is imported from magento sample and when I click on some product nothing is happening. This is my config.xml :

Comment: <events>
   <catalog_controller_product_view>
            <observers>
                <custom_catalog_controller_product_view>
                    <class>solvingmagento_orderexport/observer</class>
                    <method>observerProductClicked</method>
                </custom_catalog_controller_product_view>
            </observers>
        </catalog_controller_product_view>
  </events>

Comment: @dobrganch please post your config.xml in your question it'll be easier to read

Comment: Done ,my data is sample from magento isntallation ,I am clicking on products but nothing happen

Comment: @dobrganch you haven't declared your model class, please add the following to your `<global>` tag : `<models><solvingmagento_orderexport><class>Solvingmagento_OrderExport_Model</class></solvingmagento_orderexport></models>`

Comment: Still not working ,when I click on some product the url is like this : http://localhost/html/phpMag2/index.php/accessories/jewelry/blue-horizons-bracelets.html , shouldn't it be /catalog/product/42 or something like this ?

Comment: @dobrganch no because the URL are rewritten by Magento. That should work please add `Mage::log(__FUNCTION__);` at the top of the observer function and check your `var/log/system.log` file (ensure logs are enabled in the backend first). Also flush the cache, recompile if you use the compiler. Which Magento version are you using ?

Comment: Magento 1.9,still not working

Comment: @dobrganch which subversion of 1.9 ?

Comment: Magento 1.9.2.4

Comment: @dobrganch that's definitely the right method I don't know what's wrong